# How to Upload large .sql mb file in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

How can I upload **140mb** file on my `phpmyadmin` on my `local server` I am using **WAMP** server. When I import the file my browser getting hang and nothing will happen, and I also tried increasing time limitation in my `php.ini` file.

Comment: I recommend to use the command line tool, or any other more reliable tool instead.

Comment: +1 @KingCrunch, `mysql -h hostname -u username -p dbname < db.sql`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4755582/1172900) may be of some use to you, since it gives the command line alternative to importing a .sql file in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use source command to import large files but it s only possible through shell script or Putty

source DATABASE_FILENAME.SQL

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried compression?
If it's a table or database you're importing, there's a compression option while dumping the file. You have to choose : Custom - display all possible options and choose a compression method which saves lots of time and space.

Answer (score 2):

try compression or create a script

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file, you would add this code:

```
    php_value upload_max_filesize 80M
    php_value post_max_size 80M
    php_value max_execution_time 300
    php_value max_input_time 300
```

Hope these two links can solve your problem

[stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061589/phpmyadmin-file-too-large-error-when-trying-to-import-sql)

[second link](https://www.interspire.com/support/kb/questions/851/Overcoming+file+size+limits+when+uploading+SQL+files+to+phpMyAdmin)

Comment: but where is .htaccess file

Comment: .htaccess file is placed on your root folder.by default it is hidden

Comment: please  tell me exact pthe i am using wamp server

Answer (score 0):

If `compression` and setting limit in `php.ini` didn't solved your problem.
Try uploading in chunks.
Split your `.sql file` into number of files and import each of them separately.